# Vim sentence motion

Tags: vim

According to Vim's manual:

> A sentence is defined as ending at a '.', '!' or '?' followed by either the end of a line, or by a space or tab.

However `(` and `)` normal-mode motions seem to have no effect if there's only one space between sentences:

```
First sentence. Second sentence.
```

But `(` and `)` work as expected if there are multiple spaces between sentences:

```
First sentence.  Second sentence.
```

My question is why `(` and `)` have no effect when sentences are separated with a single space?

Comment: Add `set nocp` to your .vimrc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is documented in [Vim's manual (:help sentence)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#sentence):

> If the 'J' flag is present in 'cpoptions', at least two spaces have to
>   follow the punctuation mark; Tabs are not recognized as white space.